# Spring and Hibernate for Mulesoft developers

Tags: mule

How important is it for a mulesoft developers to know Spring and Hibernate. Should one have an in-depth knowledge about the Spring and Hibernate. If yes, could you please give an use case?

Can you give me an example for Hibernate ?. Can't we use the database connectors ? One reason could be while integrating the existing applications that are already using these frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Mule does not enforce to be expert in spring or hibernate to work on mule.
As you have pointed out its your application framework which enforce you to have in depth knowledge to work on your application while integrating with mule.

Here is [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-mule-with-spring) on how to use mule with spring.

Also refer [JPA](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-studio-dev/getting-started-with-jpa-and-mule/) module in mule.